# Gridview row update problem with text box

Tags: c#

I have one gridview. The grid view does not update the text box value -- whenever I click update, it takes my old text box value only.

This is my C# code:

```
TextBox txtqty = (TextBox)productGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("txtQty");
int qty = Convert.ToInt32(txtqty.Text.Trim());
```

If anyone could provide some assistance, I would appreciate it.

Comment: You need to update the underlying dataset?

Answer (score 0):

the following code will give you the text of the textbox...

```
string st=convert.toint32(((textbox)(productgridview.rows[e.rowindex].findcontrol("txtQty"))).text);
```

the above code will definitely work.